# TabLayout and Toolbar in same row

Tags: android, layout

I want to achieve something like this on picture:

[image: TabLayout(left) - Navigation drawer icon(Right)]

I want to have `TabLayout`(Left) `200DP`, and Burger icon for `Navigation Drawer`(Right).

Problem is that `AppBarLayout` don't support `Horizontal orientation` property. Just vertical.

I would like to import `toolbar` and `TabLayout` on same view. I saw on some apps that it's possible.

I managed to get `200DP` `TabLayout`. Other than that - nope. Tried to put all into `CoordinatorLayout` and overlay icon over the `AppBarlayout`. On designer that looks same like on picture that I posted. When I run it - I don't see that layout overlaying `AppBarLayout`. I assume that `AppBarLayout` is above it.

Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `TabLayout` and `Toolbar` both inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Meanwhile waiting for answer I solved on the same way that you said. I thought that TabLayout must be child inside AppBarLayout, I was wrong. Write answer I will accept it. ;)

Comment: Oh, it's cool. It was just a minor suggestion. If you want to keep this question, you can post an answer with the details of the setup you're using. Thank you, though. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!